# InvalidArgument trying to average Listview items

Tags: vb.net

The error occours on the 7th line of the SETAVG() sub the fuller error message is An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'.

```
Private Sub setavrg_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles setavrg.Click
    sortcol = 0
    Call sortdata()
    ListView1.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending
    Call setavg()
End Sub
Private Sub SETAVG()
    ListView1.Sorting = SortOrder.None
    Dim tmpitem As String
    Dim tmpscore As Single = 0
    Dim numcount As Single = 0
    Dim i As Integer = -1
    Dim myAVG As Single = 0
    Dim lastitem As String = Me.ListView1.Items(0).Text
    Dim lvi As ListViewItem

    For Each lvi In ListView1.Items
        i += 1
        tmpitem = lvi.SubItems(0).Text
        If tmpitem = lvi.SubItems(0).Text Then
            myAVG = tmpscore / numcount
            ListView1.Items(i - 1).SubItems(3).Text = myAVG.ToString
            tmpscore = 0
            numcount = 0
        End If
    Next
    myAVG = tmpscore / numcount
    ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(3).Text = myAVG.ToString

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the index used with `ListView1.Items` starts off at `1`, not `0`.  You are initializing `i` = `-1` and then doing `i += 1`, so, in the first loop iteration, `i` will be `0`.

Try modifying your code so that `i` is `1` in your first loop iteration.

Comment: wouldn't `i` be -1 on the first iteration, as it's being incremented (`i += 1`) then the listview is being accessed as `ListView1.Items(i - 1)`? There will also be an error on the lines using a hardcoded `0` to access the SubItems object, as that is a 1-based index as well.

Comment: minus 1 (it won't let me type -1) doesn't work either.  I'm mainly pointing out that `i` needs to be `1` or greater.

Comment: and I was just pointing out that the same issue will occur on the `SubItem` references as well, where the OP is using 0 instead of 1. your answer doesn't mention that, and OP will run into the same issue there.